# what happens if you await a coroutine that doesn't itself have await? (asyncio)

Tags: python, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand how python's asyncio, and there is one particular situation that confuses me. What happens if you await a coroutine that is just a normal routine in all but name?

I.E.:

```
async def A():
    time.wait( 1 )

async def B():
    await A()
```

Will this just run like a normal synchronous program, and thus the async and awaits are superfluous? Or will A() be split off into a separate thread to run synchronously with other awaited functions?

Comment: It will behave like a synchronous program, with the additional overhead of needing to be run through an asyncio event loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As python_user says, it's only one thread, asyncio multiplexes functions inside a single event loop. For this to work slow (IO bound but *not* CPU intensive) functions must hand back execution control to the event loop, await does this. Note time.wait() does not exist, use time.sleep(), or the awaitable asyncio.sleep().

```
import asyncio
import time

async def A():
    time.sleep(1.0)  # blocks, stops B() if called first

async def B():
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)  # hands back execution, A() can run while timing

async def main():
    t0 = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(A(), B())           # takes 2 seconds
    print(time.time() - t0)

    t0 = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(B(), A())           # takes 1 second
    print(time.time() - t0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```